# Sencha field set form panel is working in safari not in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, sencha-touch

Below code is working in Safari without any issues but same piece of code is not working in iOS. Does fieldset have any issues with iOS ?

Environment:

Sencha Touch V2.0
iOS v5.0 simulator

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',
    launch: function() {
    var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'name',
                label: 'Name'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'emailfield',
                name : 'email',
                label: 'Email'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'passwordfield',
                name : 'password',
                label: 'Password'
            }
        ]
    }]
});

    }

});
```

Could you any help us why above code is not working in iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar Problem. I set the requirements in the app.js to this

```
requires:
[
    'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    'Ext.field.Password'
]
```

worked for me, but i´m not sure it is the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see when opened at an iOS device?
I don't see any errors in your code. A fieldset in Sencha Touch normally works just fine in iOS.

Comment: It just displays white screen

Comment: I get something similar..  Running the site in Safari on an iPhone 4s ios 6.something, all works fine..  If I add the page to the Homescreen and run it, the fieldset is just a white space..  Very odd..  I assumed that both are using Safari...